# Why sizeof() operator gives different value for 'a' and "a" in C?

Tags: c, sizeof

As far as I know a character constant, viz, 'a', is stored in ASCII format which is internally treated as integer, 97 in case of 'a', that's why sizeof('a') returns 4 on executing but when I use sizeof("a") it returns 2. I have not found any explanation regarding that yet.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int x,y;

   x = sizeof('a');
   y = sizeof("a");

   printf("%d\n",x);

   printf("%d",y);
}
```

which gives the output:

```
4
2
```

Comment: 16-bit pointers? Wow, what are you learning to code on, a teapot?

Comment: In C a character literal is an `int`

Comment: @Quentin It's not a pointer, it's `const char[2]` (in C++, tags were changed).

Comment: **C** and **C++** are distinct languages and **this** is one of the questions where it actually matters.

Comment: @BaummitAugen derp. Of course it is. Coffee time!

Comment: In C, `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)` will always be true.  `sizeof('a') == 4` will not always be true, and `'a' == 97` won't always be true either (there _are_ still quite a lot of IBM mainframes running on EBCDIC).

Comment: but `sizeof("a") == 2` will always be true.

Comment: The second one is a literal array of characters, including the finishing zero. Therefore, sizeof("a") is 2 (it is equivalent to { 'a', 0 }).

The first one looks like a char type definition, but actually defaults to int size. Try: char a = 'a'; printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));

Comment: @BaummitAugen: the type of `"a"` in C is `/*readonly*/char[2]` (not `const char[2]`) -- don't know about C++.

Comment: @pmg Wasn't sure about the C situation, that's why I included the annotation. It's `const char[2]` in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'a'` is an integer. It has a size of 4 on most computers. It may also be something else, however. 2 is also common on more specialized hardware.

`"a"` is a string literal. There are two characters: `a` and `\0`. They have a size of 1 each, for a total of size 2. However, when you try to assign that, what you get usually is a `const char*` and that may have a different size.

Comment: Wow, what a mixup. Thankfully, @PaulOgilvie already edited it for me.

Comment: Were the downvotes because of the `\n` instead of `\0`? This answer is correct.

Comment: @JamesSnook you don't add the size of all elements of an array to get the size of the array? That's what was meant by adding the size of the 2 characters together.

Comment: @JamesSnook, could you tell us how then to explain this size 2?

Comment: @Kein my bad, it's been too long since I've used C, just wrote a test to double check and I was wrong.

Comment: `"a"` has type `/*readonly*/char[2]`. In most contexts it is converted to a value of type `/*readonly*/char*` (not `const char*`).

Comment: @pmg Odd that I forgot this as I used to do `int len = sizeof(array) / sizeof(arrayType)` quite often.